Displaying table content within a pgfplot
I've got a table with a binary column named xrayOn. Instead of plotting this, I want to write each xrayOn value (i.e. 0 or 1) at the position (index, 1) in a node.
However, in the code below only the addplot command works. The for loop results in the errors:

Undefined control sequence.
Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }.
Runaway argument?
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
llegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
Missing number, treated as zero.

What do I miss here? Further, I would appreciate a short explanation of when to use foreach, pgfplotsinvokeforeach or edef in the pgfplots axis enivorment.
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,decorations.text,arrows.meta,patterns,patterns.meta,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{figures/model/mytable.csv}\loadedtable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot [restrict x to domain=100:500] table [x expr={\thisrow{index}}, y expr={\thisrow{xrayOn}}, ] {\loadedtable};
    
    \foreach \i in {100,101,...,500} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{xrayOn}\of\loadedtable
        \let\indexvalue\pgfplotsretval
        \node at (axis cs: \indexvalue,1) [anchor=south] {\indexvalue}; % Position text nodes at relevant coordinates
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Does this answer your question? \foreach not behaving in axis environment

Yes, it does. They referred to the manual and on the recommended page I found the loop-in-pgfplots explanation and spotted the nodes near coords option.
With that, I can eliminate the for loop issue and it is much more convenient. Plot look nice now! :) Thanks for the quick response and have a nice weekend. :)
Cheers!

Please always complete your MWE. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Please note: The ``` marks for code has to be a line on their own to mark code blocks. See the markdown reference manual for more information. I've corrected this in your posting, so you can see the difference.

\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
index, xrayOn
0,0
11,11
22,22
33,33
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{mytable.csv}\loadedtable
\addplot table [x expr={\thisrow{index}}, y expr={\thisrow{xrayOn}}, ] {\loadedtable};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,1,...,3} {
\path \pgfextra{\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{xrayOn}\of\loadedtable} (\pgfplotsretval,1) node[anchor=south]{\pgfplotsretval};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


